# javascript validation allow only character and comma with backspace, arrow and delete keys

Tags: javascript

I need that textbox only allow characters and comma with arrow keys, backspace and delete keys

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z,]");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    </body>
```

Comment: so what is the actual question? is the used code not working?

Comment: You'll need more than a key event handler, because an input can be changed via the Edit menu or drag'n'drop.

Comment: dude HTML patterns if you don't need live validation

Comment: it works for characters and comma but backspace, delete and arrow keys not working

Comment: Your regular expression only allows letters and the comma. Besides, I am not sure if `String.fromCharCode` actually returns anything useful for control “characters” such as backspace or cursor keys.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/uc8Lhqah/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text1').keypress(function (e) {
        var k = e.which;
        var ok = k == 127 || k == 8 || k == 9 || k == 13 || k == 37 || k == 38 || k == 39 || k == 40;
        ok = ok || 
           k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
           k >= 97 && k <= 122 || // a-z
           k == 44 ; // ,

        if (!ok){
          e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's working same as mine code...... i need backspace delete and arrow keys also worked on that textbox